# Swift 4 decodable with unknown dynamic keys

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have the following JSON

```
{"DynamicKey":6410,"Meta":{"name":"","page":""}}
```

DynamicKey is unknown at compile time.I'm trying to find a reference how to 
parse this struct using decodable.

```
public struct MyStruct: Decodable {
    public let unknown: Double
    public let meta: [String: String]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case meta = "Meta"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603025/8289095

Comment: I've seen that the problem is that I don't know the name of the key is possible to do that with decodable?

Comment: Add this:  case meta = "Meta", unknown = "DynamicKey"

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk `DynamicKey` is just a random name not the actual name it would be different every time...

Comment: Ok, so at this point I would assume that the output should be a dictionary as `[DynamicKey: Meta]` since we are unable to define a specific property for it...

Comment: with dictionary its easy [String: Double] I want to parse a root level key "my_random_key": 423423

Comment: {"random_key1":6410, "random_key2": 4234234} this is the json I want to parse

Comment: And how would you access it? I mean what you should type for reading it?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/samwize/a82f29a1fb34091cd61fc06934568f82 might be useful...

Answer (score 9):

To decode an arbitrary string, you need a key like this:

```
// Arbitrary key
private struct Key: CodingKey, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
    static let meta = Key(stringValue: "Meta")!

    var description: String {
        return stringValue
    }

    var hashValue: Int { return stringValue.hash }

    static func ==(lhs: Key, rhs: Key) -> Bool {
        return lhs.stringValue == rhs.stringValue
    }

    let stringValue: String
    init(_ string: String) { self.stringValue = string }
    init?(stringValue: String) { self.init(stringValue) }
    var intValue: Int? { return nil }
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
}
```

This is a very general-purpose tool (expect for the `static let meta`) that can be used for all kinds of generic-key problems.

With that, you can find the first key that isn't `.meta` and use that as your dynamic key.

```
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)

    meta = try container.decode([String: String].self, forKey: .meta)

    guard let dynamicKey = container.allKeys.first(where: { $0 != .meta }) else {
        throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
                                                                debugDescription: "Could not find dynamic key"))
    }

    unknown = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: dynamicKey)
}
```

---

All together as a playground:

```
import Foundation

let json = Data("""
{"DynamicKey":6410,"Meta":{"name":"","page":""}}
""".utf8)

public struct MyStruct: Decodable {
    public let unknown: Double
    public let meta: [String: String]

    // Arbitrary key
    private struct Key: CodingKey, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
        static let meta = Key(stringValue: "Meta")!
        var description: String {
            return stringValue
        }

        var hashValue: Int { return stringValue.hash }

        static func ==(lhs: Key, rhs: Key) -> Bool {
            return lhs.stringValue == rhs.stringValue
        }

        let stringValue: String
        init(_ string: String) { self.stringValue = string }
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.init(stringValue) }
        var intValue: Int? { return nil }
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)

        meta = try container.decode([String: String].self, forKey: .meta)

        guard let dynamicKey = container.allKeys.first(where: { $0 != .meta }) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [],
                                                    debugDescription: "Could not find dynamic key"))
        }

        unknown = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: dynamicKey)
    }
}


let myStruct = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: json)
myStruct.unknown
myStruct.meta
```

This technique can be expanded to [decode arbitrary JSON](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/d91175be2f737aca7ad476759948666e). Sometimes it's easier to do that, and then pull out the pieces you want, then to decode each piece. For example, with the JSON gist above, you could implement `MyStruct` this way:

```
public struct MyStruct: Decodable {
    public let unknown: Double
    public let meta: [String: String]

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let json = try container.decode(JSON.self)

        guard let meta = json["Meta"]?.dictionaryValue as? [String: String] else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [],
                                                    debugDescription: "Could not find meta key"))
        }
        self.meta = meta

        guard let (_, unknownJSON) = json.objectValue?.first(where: { (key, _) in key != "Meta" }),
            let unknown = unknownJSON.doubleValue
        else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [],
                                                    debugDescription: "Could not find dynamic key"))
        }
        self.unknown = unknown
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rob nice but my implementation seems shorter

Comment: @Vyacheslav The extra baggage your removed is fine (`description`, `==`, and `hashValue` are unnecessary; they came over from my larger JSON implementation). But you changed an important part of the problem: you made everything optionals. Yes, that got you out of having to throw errors (which is why your `init` is shorter), but that changes the data structure in really important way. You also made the `let` values `var`, which again makes `init` simpler at the expense of the immutability of the object.

Comment: The choice choice to use "the first thing that decodes as Double" vs "the first key that isn't Meta" is probably fine; neither way is really checking the data very closely. But it's important to know which validation you're using. For example, if another mandatory `Double` field were added, your approach would become fragile. If another optional field (one we didn't parse) were added to the JSON, then mine would break.

Comment: @RobNapier Hi, do you think i can apply your answers to accomplish what i am asking here or i should use enum associated type or some sort of combination? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283127/swift-codable-reusing-a-subset-of-keys-shared-across-different-models-struct-cla?noredirect=1#comment117187097_66283127 . Thank you for the time

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit

var str = """
{"DynamicKey":6410,"Meta":{"name":"","page":""}}
"""
public struct MyStruct: Decodable {
    public var unknown: Double?
    public var meta: [String: String]?

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) {

        guard let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) else {
            fatalError()
        }
            for key in container.allKeys {
                unknown = try? container.decode(Double.self, forKey: key)//) ?? 0.0
                if key.stringValue == "Meta" {
                    meta = try? container.decode([String: String].self, forKey: key)
                }

            }
            print(container.allKeys)
    }

    struct CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
    let jsonData = str.data(using: .utf8)!
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let myStruct = try! jsonDecoder.decode(MyStruct.self, from: jsonData)
    print("Meta : \(myStruct.meta)")
    print("Double : \(myStruct.unknown)")
```

I've already answered a similar question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412139/1979882